# How to make child height 90% when I can't have an explicit height on container?

Tags: html, css, image, modal-dialog, lightbox

I've looked and looked and I can't find a simple solution to this problem, so maybe you guys can help me. I have a piece I'm building that mimics the functionality of a lightbox. I'll have a few images and if the user clicks one of the images it opens up the image in a large model window. The image dimensions are not uniform. I will have some tall and some short images. I need the container to have a max-height of 90% of the window, but it could be less, depending on the height of the image, so I can't just change max-height to height. The image height always needs to take up exactly 90% of the container, but it can't do that unless the height is explicitly defined for the container. Here is a js fiddle demonstrating my issue

http://jsfiddle.net/5pk52hh0/3/

```
max-height: 80%;
```

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating why I can't have explicit height on the container

http://jsfiddle.net/5pk52hh0/4/

```
height: 80%;
```

On the smaller image you can see all that extra space on the bottom, which I do not want.

Thanks for your time in advance

Comment: how about adding `min-height: 90%;` in your .lightbox img ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to put the image in a fixed position and add your close button positioned absolute to the image. That way you can give your image some margin in a different color, acting like the lightbox container.

Comment: @Andrew because the min-height: 90% would be 90% of the window, not 90% of the container because the container doesn't have a defined height

Comment: @Jan_dh because I need to keep the aspect ratio of the image, I can't set height and width to the image,  so it needs to have a container

Comment: I assumed from your exampled that all of your images were small width and big height. Aspect ratio is really annoying. Although I think it's easier to work with width rather then height. You could use javascript to calculate the height and width, check what is the biggest. If height is bigger then your width you give the image a height of 90% of the screen an auto width. If the width is bigger, you do it the other way around. You can make two classes, isvertical, is horizontal and assign the classes to the images on loading of your page.

Comment: @Jan_dh thats the solution I was considering but I assumed it to be bad practice and I was hoping there was a "cleaner" solution. Thank ya :)

Comment: There is a cleaner way if you would allow your background be 100% though.